# Why do some POSIX structures members have prefixes reflecting structure name?

Tags: c, struct, posix

Members of some (all?) structures defined in POSIX appear to have prefixes reflecting the name of the structure which contains them, like this:

```
struct timeval {
    time_t      tv_sec;     /* seconds */
    suseconds_t tv_usec;    /* microseconds */
};
struct timezone {
    int tz_minuteswest;     /* minutes west of Greenwich */
    int tz_dsttime;         /* type of DST correction */
};
```

But unlike `enum`s, `struct`s don't inject their members into outer scope. So why have these structures' members named with `tv_` and `tz_` prefixes? What could go wrong if they were instead defined like this:

```
struct timeval {
    time_t      sec;
    suseconds_t usec;
};
struct timezone {
    int minuteswest;
    int dsttime;
};
```

Were there some C implementations, which injected structure member names into outer scope, or what purpose did these prefixes have?

Comment: *don't inject their members into outer scope.* ..... sounds unfamiliar. What's that?

Comment: Early C did not have separate name-space for structure fields.  Certainly a dupe.

Comment: Additionally to the answer given there, these prefixes still serve to protect the name space of the user code. In the example you are given there could be situations where `sec` is a macro definition in user code. This would then all of a sudden collision with the use of a `sec` field of `struct timeval`.